# How to get JSON Object with specific value in Android using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-json

I would like to parse data from JSON which is String type. My JSON response looks like

```
[{"order":-1,"number":"5"},{"order":0,"number":"7"},{"order":1,"number":"3"}]
```

I tried to use next method:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray("My JSON String");

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject json_staticon = json.getJSONObject(i);

            if(json_staticon.getInt("order") == 0) {
                return json_staticon.getInt("number");
            }
        }
```

But I want to use Google GSON library to parse my JSON responses, so...
what better way to get `number` value in object with `order = 0` using GSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Gson

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Orders>>(){}.getType();
    List<Orders> details = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType); // json is your json
    for (int i = 0; i <details.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("Order is ",""+details.get(i).order); // Log the order
        Log.i("Order Number is ",""+details.get(i).number); 
    }
```

Order.java

```
  public class Orders {

   String order,number;
  }
```

Values Logged

```
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order is(2464): -1
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order Number is(2464): 5
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order is(2464): 0
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order Number is(2464): 7
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order is(2464): 1
06-15 04:22:31.282: I/Order Number is(2464): 3
```

Also instead of  `for (int i = 0; i <details.size(); i++) {` you can use enhanced for loop  `for (Orders orders: details) {`